# Issue with keyring and saving passwords

Tags: password, keyrings

Installed Ubuntu 14.04. Setup main user and keyring works as expected. Added a second user and not able to save passwords to keyring while logged onto second user. Neither login password allows the second user to save passwords. Suspect a permission issue but not sure how to correct properly.

Could someone direct me to any docs or previously asked question that will help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in another question. Just needed to use Seahorse on the second user to create a local keyring and then set it as the default one.

Comment: Please include a reference for the link to which you  refer as _"another question"_. It wil be useful to the AU community. After amaking that change by editing your own answer, please also mark your answer as THE good answer by checking the green check mark left of it.